# Freebsd and unix general,want to set F9 with tilde

Tags: freebsd, tilde

Question simple,on linux i press F9 and give me `~`
if i press F9 with ssh shell on solaris,or freebsd or
unix general give me `0~`
How to set F9 with tilde?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found
first must press

```
CTRL+V and key
```

in my case is F9
so i did

```
CTRL+V F9
```

and return this

```
^[[20~
```

Now i know is key 20 and i bind it to tilde

```
bind '"\e[20~":"~"'
```

I try if work pressing F9 and return tilde
I put this in $HOME/.profile for permanent change